# Deploying grails 2.0.3 application to cloudfoundry without cloud foundry grails-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, grails, grails-orm, cloud-foundry

I'm able to deploy my grails 2.0.3 app with the cloud foundry grails plugin and cf-push to the cloud and everything works fine.

Now i want to use the sts/eclipse cloud foundry extension to deploy with eclipse (not with grails command cf-push!) and see the server instances in server view and so on.

I create a new cloudfoundry instance with the eclipse plugin and it deploys but aborts with error message:

```
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-19036
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 377 ms
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
May 14, 2012 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader         clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named    [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@1edb587] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create   a memory leak.
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [projectBee.Requestmap.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [projectBee.Role.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 14, 2012 10:39:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

Is here somebody who knows a solution for this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the real log files which will have the stacktrace and detailed error messages. Use the vmc commandline client or STS. There is a /logs folder which probably doesn't have what you want, but also a /tomcat/logs which probably does. Also check out stacktrace.log.

Comment: Thanks Burt, I added the complete stacktrace log to my first post. I can't find the mistake...

Comment: maybe it has something to do with my bootstraps, where i create some Roles and Requestmaps?

Comment: If I deploy with cf-push using the mysql service created with sts-cf-plugin it doesn't work (same error). Using the mysql-service created by the cf-grails-plugin it works without problems! So maybe there is a mysql/service problem?

Comment: You need to find the real stacktrace from the _other_ logs; this one just says "something bad happened". Usually the localhost.2012-05-14.log file has useful info, and also look at stacktrace.log

Comment: I have this issue as well.  I can't really figure it out.  it doesn't matter which plugin I use I get the same result.

Comment: I found that my bootstrap.groovy is causing all of the issues.  however it just writes to the database, which is kind of an issue